# Modifying autoconf to properly locate header

Tags: configure, autoconf

The situation is that I am trying to get code I got off the Internet (http://findingscience.com/pymur/) to compile and I DO NOT HAVE SUDO PERMISSIONS on the machines I'm working on.

I've traced the problem down to one line in configure.ac that goes:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([indri/Index.hpp],,[
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find lemur's header files.])
])
```

Because I'm getting error messages from `./configure` that say:

```
checking indri/Index.hpp usability... no
checking indri/Index.hpp presence... no
checking for indri/Index.hpp... no
configure: error: Could not find lemur's header files.
```

I have tried directly modifying it such that `indri/Index.hpp` has hard coded path like `/path/to/indri/Index.hpp` which doesn't seem to help.

Any solution that gets the code to compile without me needing to modify directories such as /usr (since I don't have root privileges) would be appreciated.

Comment: And `./configure --prefix=/path/to` doesn't work?  What are you modifying?  How are you running `configure`?

Comment: @ldav1s The prefix option doesn't work. I'm directly modifying the `configure.ac` file, the one that's used by autoconf to generate the `configure` file.

Comment: Modifying `configure.ac` is absolutely the wrong thing to do.  Install the header in your home directory and set `CPPFLAGS` appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would do what William Pursell suggests.  Unfortunately, that won't work.  I tried it.  There's a bug in the pymur package where `configure.ac` relies on a *very old* version of the `AC_PYTHON_DEVEL` macro which clobbers `CPPFLAGS` before checking `indri/Index.hpp`, so those directories will not be in the `g++` command line.

If you want to get past that problem, you have to get a more [updated version of that macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_python_devel.html#ax_python_devel) from the Autoconf Macro Archive and copy it to `acinclude.d` (after removing `acinclude.d/ac_python_devel.m4`) and rerunning `autogen.sh`.  I was able to invoke `CPPFLAGS="-I /path/to/indri/include" ./configure` and not have it trip over that particular problem.

This is really a problem that the pymur maintainer *should fix*.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do not need or want to modify `configure.ac`.  Just install the header files somewhere that you do have write permissions and tell the configure script how to find them.  For example, if you install the headers in your HOME directory (so that $HOME/include/indri/Index.hpp exists), then run:

```
configure CPPFLAGS=-I$HOME/include
```

That should work on the majority of platforms.  Note that modifying configure.ac with the path `/path/to/indri/Index.hpp` will fail because your toolchain will use that as a relative path and is probably looking in places like `/usr/include/path/to/indri/Index.hpp`.